# Grails - Convert Server (UTC Date) to User Date in Controller

Tags: grails, groovy, timezone

I'm trying to convert some dates that I have stored on the server (in UTC). I'd like to convert them to the user's time so it would be pretty for their time zone.

However, I'm not sure about how to go about doing that. What's the best practice to get the user's timezone from the request in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timezone is not passed in the request headers. If you had the users time zone stored in a profile setting then you can easily format the date according to this but its not something you can just grab from the request. There are ways to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: Ah, so it would make sense for that to be held as a user property?